# How to query record in Rails 2 without initializing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

How can I query a record in Rails 2 without initializing the record?

For example, when calling Event.first the first record is fetched and an after_initialize method in the model is called which I would like to avoid. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One option appears to be to get the raw sql data with

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT events.id FROM events")
results.each{|result| puts result }
```